# Create a UIViewController concrete class from its type

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to create a concrete class from UIViewController type, something like this

```
 func create(with type : UIViewController.Type)->UIViewController{
       return type.init(coder: NSCoder())!
    }
```

Apparently, UIViewController's designated initializer is only init(coder : NSCoder). And, when I try to pass in NSCoder() (as shown in the above case), the app crashes.

Anyone knows a better solution in creating a UIViewController concrete class from its type? Or am I pass in the wrong NSCoder in this case?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to dc

Comment: Are you trying to keep a copy of current instance of controller?

Comment: Can't you use instantiante the class from a Storyboard as it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Code completion does not show this option, but this compiles and runs without a problem:

```
func create(with type : UIViewController.Type) -> UIViewController {
    return type.init()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create the view controller programmatically or from a XIB then just use the base constructor.

```
let viewController = MyViewController()
```

If you have a XIB with the same file name as the class then it will load it automatically.

If you want to load it from a storyboard then you need to define an identifier for the view controller in the storyboard and then call:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil)
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewControllerIdentifier")
```

**EDIT**

If you want a special `create` function, you can actually create an extension for `UIViewController` like this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    static func create() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}
```

Then you can call `let myViewController = MyViewController.create()`. However, unless you want to do something special in that `create` function it's a bit unnecessary.